# How do I specify Permissions in a custom app consent policy?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have successfully made a Custom App Consent Policy using `New-AzureADMSPermissionGrantConditionSet` and following the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/manage-app-consent-policies#create-a-custom-app-consent-policy). I specified `ClientApplicationIds` and it works great.

Now I also want to specify the permissions that must match. On Permissions, the docs say:

[image: Docs on Permissions condition for New-AzureADMSPermissionGrantConditionSet]

I need help understanding (and accessing) the permission IDs in the "OAuth2Permissions property of the API's ServicePrincipal object".

What ServicePrincipal is the doc referring to? The one in the application’s Home Tenant, or one in the Tenant that is using the application? If the app has not been consented to yet, then there is no ServicePrinciple in the Tenant using the app so I have a chicken-and-egg problem.

And what are the Permissions I'm expecting to get? I'm wondering why MS didn't just let us pass the scopes as strings e.g. `email`, `mail.read` etc. I don't understand exactly what the Permissions are in this particular context.

Comment: The service principal it's referring to there is the service principal for the API. (For example, Microsoft Graph, or your own custom API.) You don't really have a chicken-and-egg problem because if the API's service principal doesn't exist in the tenant, sign-in will fail anyway, regardless of whether the user can consent.

I added another answer showing how to retrieve the permissions IDs using Azure AD PowerShell, based on the string claim values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need help understanding (and accessing) the permission IDs in the "OAuth2Permissions property of the API's ServicePrincipal object".

The permission ID means the `id` of the Delegated permission of the API( i.e. `oauth2Permissions` defined in the API) you added in the client app registration.

For example, you created a multi-tenant client app in tenant A, you added the `Mail.Read` *Delegated permission* of **Microsoft Graph**, by default, there would also be a `User.Read` *Delegated permission* automatically, so there are two permissions totally in the `API permissions` of your client app.

Now, you want to use the custom app consent policy in tenant B, you want the user to consent the two permissions, then the `-Permissions` should be the `id` of the two permission defined in Microsoft Graph, to find it easily, just navigate to the client app in tenant A -> `Manifest`, then you can get the `id`s like below.

[image]

The complete command should be

```
New-AzureADMSPermissionGrantConditionSet `
    -PolicyId "joy-custom-policy" `
    -ConditionSetType "includes" `
    -PermissionType "delegated" `
    -ResourceApplication "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" `
    -Permissions @("e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d","570282fd-fa5c-430d-a7fd-fc8dc98a9dca")
```

---

In another scenario, you use the [custom API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis)(created in tenant A) in the client app instead of a Microsoft API.

If so, you need to grant admin consent for the API App in tenant B first, otherwise you will get an error `The app needs access to a service (\"api://tenantA/myapi\") that your organization (tenant B) has not subscribed to or enabled`, or you can use the admin account to run `New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId <appid of the API app>` in tenant B, it will also work, after consent, the normal user will be able to consent the permission you defined in the policy.

---

**Note:** Sometimes, you may get an error `This app may be risky` like below.

[image]

This means Microsoft detects a risky end-user consent request, the request will require a step-up to admin consent instead, if you still want the user to consent the permission, you need to [disable the risk-based step-up consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent?tabs=azure-powershell#disable-or-re-enable-risk-based-step-up-consent-using-powershell) first, then the user will be able to consent the permission.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for a thorough explanation Joy. When there are multiple permission like in your example, how can I see the details so I know which is which? Anyway I'm up and running now. Thank you.  BTW I never clicked on Manifest before! What a useful tab. :)

Comment: @TrevorJ You could get the object id of the API's service principal in the tenant, then use `(Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId xxx).Oauth2Permissions`, you will find them in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for how you would get the permission IDs for three delegated permissions for Microsoft Graph, using Azure AD PowerShell:

```bsh
# The appId for the client application
$clientAppId = "{client-app-id}"

# The claim values for the Microsoft Graph delegated permissions to include
$claimValues = @("User.Read", "Mail.Send", "User.ReadBasic.All")

# Get the service principal for Microsoft Graph
$resource = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "servicePrincipalNames/any(n:n eq 'https://graph.microsoft.com')"

# Get the delegated permission IDs for the given claim values
$permissionIds = $resource.OAuth2Permissions `
  | ? { $claimValues.Contains($_.Value) } | select -ExpandProperty Id

# Use these permission IDs in a condition set for a custom permission grant policy
New-AzureADMSPermissionGrantConditionSet `
    -PolicyId "my-custom-policy" `
    -ConditionSetType "includes" `
    -ClientApplicationIds @($clientAppId) `
    -PermissionType "delegated" `
    -ResourceApplication $resource.AppId `
    -Permissions $permissionIds
```